# include_vars and unknown variable

Tags: ansible

I want to use Custom variable files but I have an error. please explain me How can I have a custom variable file?
my `vars/var1.yml` is :

```
---
ip_ssh_srv1: 192.168.10.10
```

and `vars/var2.yml` is :

```
---
ip_ssh_srv2: 192.168.10.20
```

my `task.yml` is :

```
---
    - include_vars:
        file: var1.yml
        file: var2.yml

     - name: -- my task --
      template: src=db_info.j2 dest=/root/db_info.cnf
```

and my output is :

```
[root@anisble ansible]# ansible-playbook playbooks/get_ip_ssh.yml                                            

TASK [Gathering Facts] 

*********************************************************************

ok: [db1]                                                                                                    
ok: [db3]                                                                                                    

TASK [ssh : include_vars] ***************************************************************
ok: [db1]                                                                                                    
ok: [db2]                                                                                                    
TASK [ssh : -- my task --] *******************************************************************
fatal: [db1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ip_ssh_srv1' is undefined"}    
fatal: [db2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ip_ssh_srv2' is undefined"}    

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************
db1                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1                                  
db2                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

why unknown variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake 1**

You seem to including an unspecified vars file.

**Mistake 2**

You should not define the same keys multiple times.

This is a YAML dictionary:

```
- include_vars:
    file: var1.yml
    file: var2.yml
```

It is syntactically correct, but you defined the same key `file` twice.

When Ansible queries it, it can get only a single value for the `file` key value (`var2.yml`).

---

If you look at the [`include_vars` module docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_vars_module.html), you'll find a few ways to include multiple files (but none through defining the same key), for example:

```
- include_vars:
    dir: vars
    files_matching: var
```